# Avoid duplicates on a row under 2 columns SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I create a constraint to avoid duplicates among 2 columns on the same row for example:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| Id | Code1 | Code2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | x     | x     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

where each single row, Code1 cannot equal Code2.

Comment: I think you would need to write a trigger.

Comment: Iirc, `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (code1 <> code2)` does the trick. You may want to cater for null values in code1, code2, eg. by defaulting to a value at least one of the cols will never contain: `nvl(code1, 42) <> nvl(code2, 42)`.

Comment: Are you looking for a [unique constraint](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check constraint to the table comparing the columns:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_UniqueCodeOnRow 
CHECK( Code1 <> Code2 )
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac9db/2)**

---

**Update**

Per @collapsar's comment above, if the columns are nullable you may also want to cater for that (i.e. if you don't want Code1 and Code2 to contain null values, though you're happy for one or the other to).

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_UniqueCodeOnRow 
CHECK( Code1 <> Code2 AND NOT ( Code1 IS NULL AND Code2 IS NULL) )
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7006c/2)**

Answer (score -1):

Did you define unique key to other columns?

If you don't want the insertion to be done i-e, if CODE1 = CODE2 should not be performed, define unique key to the relevant column(s).

Though, you may find other threads running the same query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would that help? The uniqueness refers to the column values wrt different rows in the table. That doesn't rule out identity in some record( even in every record, fwiw)

Comment: Okay then the good idea would be to hold on to the thought that no same combination should be repeated, like  X Y, Y X, X X, Y Y